# How to fix the error "vncserver: The HOME environment variable is not set" - run a Python script from PHP on behalf of the user?

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, vnc

The script in ** Python ** is run from ** PHP **. The script runs normally, but reaching the lines of launch ** vncserver ** - it cannot run it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import time
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient
from multiprocessing import Pool
import json
import math 
import subprocess
import os
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
.
.
.

    ## VNC Display checks
    # Configure DISPLAY variable to VNC
    os.environ["DISPLAY"] = cfg["vnc_display"]
    if os.system("xhost >& /dev/null"):
        print("WARNING: No VNC display opened under %s. Running VNC Server and trying again" % (os.environ["DISPLAY"]))
        os.system("vncserver %s" % (os.environ["DISPLAY"]))
        time.sleep(5)
        if os.system("xhost >& /dev/null"):
            print("ERROR: No VNC display opened under %s. Cannot continue" % (os.environ["DISPLAY"]))
            return
.
.
.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    command_line_runner()
```

stops work and displays a message:

**vncserver: The HOME environment variable is not set

No VNC display opened under :1.

Running VNC Server and trying again.

ERROR: No VNC display opened under :1.

Cannot continue.**

As I understand it, ** vncserver ** does not want to start with user privileges ** Apache **, but only from under the user - the error is related to execution rights. Because if you run the script directly, on the command line, on behalf of the user - there are no errors and everything works fine.
I think I need to teach somehow the script to work correctly with ** Apache ** privileges, but I don’t know how to do it. Please suggest solutions. Thank.

Comment: "The HOME environment variable is not set" the error is right there. You haven't set HOME.

Comment: Perhaps try setting the `HOME` variable with `os.environ`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following lines of code and everything started working as needed:

```
.
.
.
from os.path import expanduser
HOME = expanduser("~")
.
.
.
os.environ["HOME"] = HOME
```

Helped tips:  [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill), [Anaksunaman](https://superuser.com/users/302907/anaksunaman)